# Binary searching via bitmasking?

Tags: algorithm, scala, bit-manipulation, binary-search, bitmask

I have used this algorithm many times to binary search over `Ints` or `Longs`. Basically, I start from `Long.MinValue` and `Long.MaxValue` and decide to set the bit at `i`th position depending on the value of the function I am maximizing (or minimizing). In practice, this turns out to be faster (exactly 63*2 bitwise operations) and easier to code and avoids the many [gotchas of traditional binary search implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504335/what-are-the-pitfalls-in-implementing-binary-search).

Here is my algorithm in Scala:

```
/**
 * @return Some(x) such that x is the largest number for which f(x) is true
 *         If no such x is found, return None
 */
def bitBinSearch(f: Long => Boolean): Option[Long] = {
  var n = 1L << 63
  var p = 0L
  for (i <- 62 to 0 by -1) {
    val t = 1L << i
    if (f(n + t)) n += t
    if (f(p + t)) p += t
  }
  if (f(p)) Some(p) else if (f(n)) Some(n) else None
}
```

I have 3 questions:

- What is this algorithm called in literature? Surely, I can't be the inventor of this - but, I did not find anything when I tried googling for various combinations of binary-search + bit-masking/toggling. I have been personally calling it "bitBinSearch". I have not seen this mentioned at all in articles going over binary search over an `Int` or `Long` domain where this would be trivial to write.
- Can the code be improved/shortened in anyway? Right now I keep track of the negative and positive solutions in `n` and `p`. Any clever way I can merge them  into single variable? Here are some sample test cases: http://scalafiddle.net/console/70a3e3e59bc61c8eb7acfbba1073980c before you attempt an answer
- Is there a version that can be made to work with `Double`s and `Float`s?

Comment: I would think that bit toggling is an implementation detail and does not matter: the algorithm is still called binary search.

Comment: @Bergi: To clarify - I know the algorithm is still binary search in general; but, what is this specific implementation called?

Comment: Improved?  You don't need to shift by t by i every time, instead you can shift by a constant.  Init t to 1 << 62, and each iteration shift right one bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you're bit-twiddling (a popular pastime in some circles) why not go all the way?  I don't know if there's any efficiency to be gained, but I think it actually makes the algorithm a little clearer.

```
def bitBinSearch(f: Long => Boolean): Option[Long] = {
  var n = Long.MinValue
  var p = 0L
  var t = n >>> 1
  while (t > 0) {
    if ( f(n|t) ) n |= t
    if ( f(p|t) ) p |= t
    t >>= 1
  }
  List(p,n).find(f)
}
```

Of course, if you go recursive you can eliminate those nasty `var`s.

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
@tailrec
def bitBinSearch( f: Long => Boolean
                , n: Long = Long.MinValue
                , p: Long = 0L
                , t: Long = Long.MinValue >>> 1 ): Option[Long] = {
  if (t > 0) bitBinSearch(f
                         , if (f(n|t)) n|t else n
                         , if (f(p|t)) p|t else p
                         , t >> 1
                         )
  else List(p,n).find(f)
}
```

Again, probably not more efficient, but perhaps a bit more Scala-like.

**UPDATE**

Your comment about Int/Long got me wondering if one function could do it all.

After traveling down a few dead-ends I finally came up with this (which is, oddly, actually pretty close to your original code).

```
import Integral.Implicits._
import Ordering.Implicits._
def bitBinSearch[I](f: I => Boolean)(implicit ev:Integral[I]): Option[I] = {
  def topBit(x: I = ev.one):I = if (x+x < ev.zero) x else topBit(x+x)
  var t:I = topBit()
  var p:I = ev.zero
  var n:I = t+t
  while (t > ev.zero) {
    if ( f(p+t) ) p += t
    if ( f(n+t) ) n += t
    t /= (ev.one+ev.one)
  }
  List(p,n).find(f)
}
```

This passes the following tests.

```
assert(bitBinSearch[Byte] (_ <= 0) == Some(0))
assert(bitBinSearch[Byte] (_ <= 1) == Some(1))
assert(bitBinSearch[Byte] (_ <= -1) == Some(-1))
assert(bitBinSearch[Byte] (_ <= 100) == Some(100))
assert(bitBinSearch[Byte] (_ <= -100) == Some(-100))
assert(bitBinSearch[Short](_ <= 10000) == Some(10000))
assert(bitBinSearch[Short](_ <= -10000) == Some(-10000))
assert(bitBinSearch[Int]  (_ <= Int.MinValue) == Some(Int.MinValue))
assert(bitBinSearch[Int]  (_ <= Int.MaxValue) == Some(Int.MaxValue))
assert(bitBinSearch[Long] (_ <= Long.MinValue) == Some(Long.MinValue))
assert(bitBinSearch[Long] (_ <= Long.MaxValue) == Some(Long.MaxValue))
assert(bitBinSearch[Long] (_ < Long.MinValue) == None)
```

Comment: Very nice! I like that this can be easily converted to support `f: Int => Boolean` unlike my original code, where you'd have to change the 63 and 62 etc

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Scala, but this is my version of Binary searching via bitmasking in java

My algorithm is like this

We start with the index with highest power of 2 and end at 2<sup>0</sup>. Every time we see 
`A[itemIndex] ≤ A[index]` we update `itemIndex += index`
After the iteration `itemIndex` gives the index of the item if present in the array else gives the floor value in A

```
int find(int[] A, int item) { // A uses 1 based indexing
    int index = 0;
    int N = A.length;
    for (int i = Integer.highestOneBit(N); i > 0; i >>= 1) {
        int j = index | i;
        if (j < N && A[j] <= item) {
            index = j;
            if (A[j] == item) break;
        }
    }
    return item == A[index] ? index : -1;
}
```