# Why recursive Binary search sometimes cause stack overflow for some but not all non existing inputs?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, binary-search

I'm implementing a recursive python binary search function That works fine for most inputs but seems to cause stack overflow for some but not all non existing list elements which I can't see why is this behavior
the code is

```py
def recursive_binary_search(start: int, end: int, search:int, array: list):
    """
    :param start: start index
    :param end: end index
    :param search: integer to search find
    :param array: Sorted array to search
    :return: True if found, False if Not
    """

    if (end == start) and array[start] != search: return False
    if (end == start) and array[start] == search: return True

    middle_index = (end+start)//2
    if array[middle_index] == search: return True

    elif array[middle_index] > search:
        res = recursive_binary_search(start, middle_index-1, search, array)
        return res
    elif array[middle_index] < search:
        res = recursive_binary_search(middle_index+1, end, search, array)
        return res
```

the list is `sorted_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 7, 9, 10, 14, 80]` inputs seeming to cause overflow are `6` `11` and return `False` as normal for inputs like `8` and `100` and `15` . The function is called as `print(recursive_binary_search(0, len(sorted_list)-1, 11, sorted_list))`

Comment: Supposing middle_index is start or end (as is likely). Your next call will need to check the case where end < start

Comment: it works this way but can't see why it crashes for some non existing input while work's with some non existing inputs like ```15``` , ```100``` or ```8``` can't see the reason

Comment: Well, what do you see in your tracing output?  You didn't include that in your post.  That output should show the problems pretty quickly.

Comment: Binary search is harder than it looks.  Check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/504335/5987 or https://reprog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/are-you-one-of-the-10-percent/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem when `start` and `end` are one index apart. In the example you've given, when you reach `start=8` and `end=9`, you'll have `middle_index=8`, then if `array[middle_index] > search`, you'll call the function with `start=8` and `end=7`, which is invalid, and will recurse forever.

You can fix this infinite recursion by relaxing the end condition to use `<=` instead of `==`:

```
if (end <= start) and array[start] != search: return False
if (end <= start) and array[start] == search: return True
```

Side note - this condition could be simplified as follows:

```
if (end <= start): return array[start] == search
```