# An error in a code about binary search in The C Programming Language book by Dennis M. Ritchie?

Tags: c, function, binary-search

In [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqZko.png) (section 3.3) from *The C Programming Language book by Dennis M. Ritchie and Brian W. Kerninghan*, I think there is something wrong with this code, and indeed when I ran it, it indeed didn't work as expected.

Here is the original code from the book:

```
/* binsearch: find x in v[0] <= v[1] <= ... <= v[n-1] */
int binsearch(int x, int v[], int n)
{
    int low, high, mid;

    low = 0;
    high = n - 1;
    while (low <= high) {
        mid = (low+high)/2;
        if (x < v[mid])
            high = mid + 1;
        else if (x > v[mid])
            low = mid + 1;
        else /* found match */
            return mid;
    }
    return -1; /* no match */
}
```

So, this function here is supposed to search for an integer in an array of integers and then if it found it, the function will return its position, otherwise it will return -1. And the first obvious wrong thing in it is the test `low <= high` in the wile loop, which will always stay True in this function, and therefore this loop will run indefinitely and never end (and this is what happened when I ran it, it got stuck in an infinite loop apparently(edit: if x is not in v, otherwise it works correctly but a good program is supposed to cover all cases)), and the solution to this is to remove the "or equals" part of the test, meaning to change it to `low < high`. And the second mistake is with the first `if` statement, because when it finds that `x < v[mid]` it sets `high` to `mid + 1` which is obviously wrong because if x value is less than the middle value (The v array is sorted) then x will be in the indexes less than the middle index and therefore the range that we should check would be `0` to `mid -1` but that is not the case, because in the book they included mid and mid + 1 in the range which we know they are greater than x (because x < v[mid]), so they should have set high to `mid - 1` instead.

So, my question is: Did they really make a mistake in this example, or did I misunderstand? And if they did, is what I said about the mistakes correct or not? And finally, here's an implementation of the function along with the corrections I stated above in this C code (that worked as intended when I executed it) below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int binsearch(int x, int v[], int n);

int main() {
    int n = 10, x = 25;
    int v[10] = {0, 5, 10, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 70};
    int position = binsearch(x, v, n) + 1;
    if (position) /*equivalent to (position != 0) since position will equal 0 when binsearch returns -1*/
        printf("x is at: %d", position);
    else
        printf("x is not found.");
    return 0;
}

int binsearch(int x, int v[], int n) {
    int low, high ,mid;
    low = 0;
    high = n - 1;
    while (low < high) {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (x < v[mid])
            high = mid - 1;
        else if (x > v[mid])
            low = mid + 1;
        else /* found match */
            return mid;
    }
    return -1; /* no match */
}
```

And one last question, when x is indeed in v at the end when the corresponding index will be found it will be returned in the `return mid;` statement but then when we get out of the while loop, we find that -1 will also be returned, wouldn't that overwrite the returned value from the while loop?

Comment: You mentioned that "it indeed didn't work as expected", but you did not provide any details of what you expected to happen or of what actually happened.

Comment: @jarmod I did say it gets stuck in an infinite loop, and I also stated the expected behavior above

Comment: @jarmod sorry, I am still new to the platform can you please fix it :)

Comment: Are you saying that the posted test code (shown in main above) plus the original K&R code for `binsearch` actually runs indefinitely for you?

Comment: post the actual code original infinite loop code, not an image please.

Comment: In my edition of the book (1978) the function is just called `binary` and does indeed do `high = mid - 1;`. The *real* bug in this code is `(low+high)/2;`which might overflow, but that wasn't discovered until much later (when memory grew bigger).

Comment: @BoP I don't understand how it might overflow

Comment: @jarmod exactly that is what happens

Comment: Can I ask where you got the code for binsearch from? It's bugged. The 2nd edition corrects this bug.

Comment: @jarmod I found it in a pdf version of the book from the web

Comment: Same typo here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69557572/binary-search-in-kernighan-and-ritchies-c-book

Comment: @oabdullae - If you have an array large enough, `low + high` can be larger than what fits in an `int`.

Comment: Later versions of binary search tend to use `mid = low + (high - low) / 2;`

Comment: There's been multiple errata regarding this book, official and unofficial both. To the point where you can't really trust anything without the erratas next to you. My general recommendation is to abandon the book entirely since it is also hopelessly outdated and filled with bad practices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 1st edition of K&R appears to include the following code which is indeed bugged and can loop forever:

```
/* binsearch: find x in v[0] <= v[1] <= ... <= v[n-1] */
int binsearch(int x, int v[], int n)
{
    int low, high, mid;
    low = 0;
    high = n - 1;
    while (low <= high) {
        mid = (low+high)/2;
        if (x < v[mid])
            high = mid + 1; /* bug here */
        else if (x > v[mid])
            low = mid + 1;
        else /* found match */
            return mid;
    }
    return -1; /* no match */
}
```

The 2nd edition of K&R includes the following, corrected version:

```
/* binsearch: find x in v[0] <= v[1] <= ... <= v[n-1] */
int binsearch(int x, int v[], int n)
{
    int low, high, mid;
    low = 0;
    high = n - 1;
    while (low <= high) {
        mid = (low+high)/2;
        if (x < v[mid])
            high = mid - 1; /* correction here */
        else if (x > v[mid])
            low = mid + 1;
        else /* found match */
            return mid;
    }
    return -1; /* no match */
}
```

Comment: I sincerely hope that nobody is using the 1st edition for study purposes in 2023. This binary search bug would be the very least of their problems.

Answer (score 2):

> And one last question, when x is indeed in v at the end when the
> corresponding index will be found it will be returned in the return
> mid; statement but then when we get out of the while loop, we find
> that -1 will also be returned, wouldn't that overwrite the returned
> value from the while loop?

No, when the function reaches the `return` statement it terminates its execution and returns to the caller. You misunderstood how functions work.

When you are on the train you leave it on station A. The train continues to the station B. Can you leave it there? No - because you are not on the train anymore.

Comment: oh ok I 've just learned that from you, thanks :)

Comment: @oabdullae the upvote and accept

Comment: I would upvote but I can't since I don't have enough reputation to do so. and for accepting I still didn't get the answer to my main question which are the "mistakes" that I found in the function

Comment: @oabdullae Your question was _"Did they really make a mistake in this example, or did I misunderstand?"_ - And I think you got an answer to that, right?

Comment: @TedLyngmo nope not yet. This answer is bou the general function behavior. And there's no other answer that answered my question.

Comment: @TedLyngmo can you please write a detailed answer why the answer is **no** because I still can't see how this code is correct especially when I executed it and THe program got stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: @oabdullae Sorry, I just noticed that they have `high = mid + 1;` in their algorithm. If you didn't type it in wrong, that _is_ a mistake in the book. It _should_ be `high = mid - 1;`.  Your code on the other hand has another mistake which makes it miss a lot of numbers. Comparison: https://godbolt.org/z/WjrhTevTn

Comment: @TedLyngmo I don't see how it can miss numbers, the logic in my corrected version is very straightforward and it applies the binary search algorithm as it is defined, can you give me an array that will show how my version will miss numbers, and for the link you provide I checked it but didn't fully understand the code because I'm still not familiar with some concepts in it like pointers

Comment: @oabdullae it's beause you changed `<=` to `<`. That makes it miss numbers where low and high becomes equal. The output from my example shows you numbers your algorithm misses. You don't have to understand the drivercode. Just look at the output

Comment: @0___________ I upvoted now that I am able to, since I gained some reputation

Comment: @TedLyngmo I still didn't get what you mean in the output. can you just give one example where my version will fail so I can visualize the problem more clearly?

Comment: @oabdullae Given the array `int v[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};` where `n = 11`, let your algorithm search for `1`, `4`, `7` or `10`. It will miss all of them. That's what the output of my comparison program shows. If you still don't see why, try to find those numbers manually with pen and paper while using your algorithm. A simpler example: `int v[] = {1};` where `n = 1` - Your algorithm will miss that too: https://godbolt.org/z/d4o7vEon5

Comment: @oabdullae Here's the same test code with a clearer output: https://godbolt.org/z/Edvazf4dW

Comment: @TedLyngmo ok thanks I'll try to understand it with these examples

Comment: @oabdullae It really comes down to the change from `<=` to `<` where you miss the number when low and high becomes equal. Try it with pen and paper with `int v[1] = {1};`. In that, low and high both start a `0` - so `low < high` will be `false` and it'll return that it couldn't find the number.

Comment: @TedLyngmo oh yeah you are absolutely right; Thanks